# Gambian national traveling to Gambia having four hours transit in morroco Casablanca do I need a transit visa

Tags: transit-visas, morocco, casablanca, cmn, gambian-citizens

k am a Gambian national traveling to Gambia do I need a  four hour transit visa to morroco Cassablanca